# Getting the latest Value with a Condition from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a query from multiple tables using Left Joins, at the moment my issue is that I'm searching for a Unique Value called Design Code but a Design Code can be in multiple Deal's. For example:

```
id  designcode_id   deal_id used
206 100192  34  1
16816   100192  1789    1
20419   100192  2237    1
20797   100192  2298    1
```

Now when I do my search on my Code I get those 4 Deals, and I wish to get only the latest Deal in this case:

```
id  designcode_id   deal_id used
20797   100192  2298    1
```

So it should be only putting one line per Design Code with the highest Deal id (for the example 2298).

This is my Code:

I have try the Functions Distinct and MAX but doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
deals.deal_id as "Deal ID",
accounts.account_name as "Account",
deals.deal_name as "Deal Name",
designcodes.id as "Designcode ID",
styles.style_number as "Style ID",
styles.style_name "Style Type",
case when artjobs.type_id = 10 then 'Prodcution' 
when artjobs.type_id = 1 then 'Concept'
when artjobs.type_id = 2 then 'Draft'
when artjobs.type_id = 3 then 'Revision'
when artjobs.type_id = 4 then 'Store Images'
else 'Unknown Type' end as "Type of Artjob",
case when artjobs.status_id = 100 then 'Complete' else 'Unknown Status' end as "Art Job Status",
case when artjobs.due_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY) then 'Under 25 Days'
when artjobs.due_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY) then 'Over 25 Days'
end as "Date Evaluation",
artjobs.due_date as "Due Date"
from artjobs
left join arttasks on artjobs.id = arttasks.artjob_id
left join designcodes on arttasks.designcode_id = designcodes.id
left join designcode_deal on designcodes.id = designcode_deal.designcode_id
left join deals on designcode_deal.deal_id = deals.deal_id
left join accounts on deals.account_id = accounts.account_id
left join styles on designcodes.style_id = styles.style_id
WHERE 
designcode_deal.designcode_id in (
100192,
100194,
100232
)
-- and artjobs.due_date>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
-- and artjobs.type_id = 10
-- and artjobs.status_id =100
order by artjobs.type_id asc
```

At the end I wish it would only show the latest information.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: It totally depends on what does it mean, " latest information."  One option is `Order by` relevant column `DESC`, `LIMIT` relevant mumber or rows.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to outer join the design code tables, when you want to show result rows for certain design codes. Then, do you want to show result rows for codes that are not used in any deal yet? –

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get the question that Clear: 


_Which MySQL version are you using?_
The version I'm using is: 5.7.27

_It totally depends on what does it mean, " latest information." One option is Order by relevant column DESC, LIMIT relevant mumber or rows._
As for what I mean by latest is the highest Deal ID in my query for Example I run it for a Design Code: 100192, and got this response with 8 Rows, for 4 different Deals (as the Design Code my show on multiple Deals). For example showed me Deal id: 2298, and 2237 I want just the result of 2298 as it is higher than the other.

Comment: _It doesn't seem to make sense to outer join the design code tables, when you want to show result rows for certain design codes. Then, do you want to show result rows for codes that are not used in any deal yet?_

In this case yes if the Design code is require even not being used it should appear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by "your_deal_id" desc then you get the latest, asuming that you have a increment id

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although this orders it but it doesn't stop from showing the rest of the response of the Query for the single Design Code, so in this case I get that the Design Code: 100192 is on the Deal ID's: 2298, 2237, 1789 and 34, in this case I wish to only display the result of Deal ID 2298 as it will be the highest one (therefore the latest).